# Delete con Select en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas, he intentado hacer una consulta para eliminar todos los tickets que no tengan detalles, pero me da un error de sintaxis sql.

```
DELETE FROM ticket t JOIN ticketdetail td ON t.id = td.idticket WHERE 
(SELECT count(*) FROM td JOIN t ON t.id = td.idticket) = 0;
```

La relacion de las tablas es la siguiente: Ticket guarda un campo id que actúa como primary key y ticketdetail tiene un campo idticket que sería su foreign key.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si no me equivoco falta la palabra inner, sería DELETE FROM ticket t INNER JOIN ticketdetail td ON t.id = td.idticket WHERE 
(SELECT count(*) FROM td INNER JOIN t ON t.id = td.idticket) = 0; No se si pasa algo más

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más simple de hacer lo que quieres sería con `LEFT JOIN`, pues `idticket` será `NULL` en aquellas filas que no haya coincidencias.

```
DELETE t FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticketdetail td ON t.id=td.idticket 
WHERE td.idticket IS NULL;
```

Veamos una prueba de concepto:

### Código

<kbd>**[VER DEMO  EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/TPVV81936)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ticket_name VARCHAR(25)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_name)
    VALUES 
        ('Ticket 1'),
        ('Ticket 2'),
        ('Ticket 3')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket_detail 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ticket_id INT,
    ticket_fecha DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_ticket(ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE  
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO ticket_detail (ticket_id,ticket_fecha)
    VALUES 
    (1,'2016-10-12'),
    (1,'2016-10-13'),
    (2,'2016-10-14'),
    (1,'2016-10-15'),
    (1,'2016-10-16'),
    (2,'2017-10-17')
;

/*Antes del borrado*/
SELECT * FROM ticket;

DELETE t FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_detail td ON t.id=td.ticket_id 
WHERE td.ticket_id IS NULL;

/*Después del borrado*/
SELECT * FROM ticket;
```

### Resultado:

```
-Antes

id  ticket_name
1   Ticket 1
2   Ticket 2
3   Ticket 3

-Después

id  ticket_name
1   Ticket 1
2   Ticket 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es borrar los tickets que no tengan detalles, es decir que quieres borrar los tickets que NO EXISTAN en la tabla TicketDetail. Para ello simplemente has de realizar una subconsulta sobre ticketDetail:
`SELECT * FROM ticketdetail;`

Con lo que tu `DELETE` quedaría así:

`DELETE FROM ticket 
WHERE id NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM ticketdetail);`

De esta forma estás eliminando todos los tickets que NO EXISTAN en la tabla ticketDetails.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta consulta:

```
DELETE FROM ticket where id not in
(SELECT t.id FROM ticket t join ticketdetail td on t.id = td.idticket)
```

Al usar la claúsula JOIN le estamos indicando que es una relación de tipo INNER JOIN. Si en la tabla ticketdetail dicho ticket no tiene ningún detalle, entonces en nuestro SELECT no se va a mostrar dicho ID. Eso quiere decir que solamente se están mostrando los ID que tienen detalle; por consiguiente, los que no se muestran son aquellos que no tienen detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `JOIN` en el `DELETE` tienes que especificar la tabla de la que querrás que se borren los registros, prueba lo siguiente:

```
DELETE ticket 
FROM ticket 
JOIN ticketdetail td ON t.id = td.idticket 
WHERE (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM td 
       JOIN t ON t.id = td.idticket) = 0;
```